# VBA Inserting Chart At Same Position In Each Page

Tags: vba, ms-word

I extracted the values of each cell from the table in word document, and I created charts based on those values. The charts are fine.

However, it keep insert at the first page. Does anyone know how can I insert my chart in at same position in each page?

The word document generated by Mail Merge. Will that cause the problem?

Also, dose anyone know how to insert a chart into table cell?

```
Dim pge As Page
Dim i As Integer
i = 3
Dim j As Integer
j = 1

For peg = 1 To Selection.Information(wdNumberOfPagesInDocument)
        Dim tTable As Table

        Set tTable = ActiveDocument.Tables(i)
        Set cTable = ActiveDocument.Tables(j)


        Dim wChart As Chart
        Dim chartWorkSheet As Excel.Worksheet
        Dim ThisYrSumCon As Integer
        Dim ThisYrWinCon As Integer
        Dim PreYrSumCon As Integer
        Dim PreYrWinCon As Integer
        Dim BefPreYrSumCon As Integer
        Dim BefPreYrWinCon As Integer

        '•
        ThisYrSumCon = CInt(Left(tTable.Cell(2, 2).Range.Text, Len(tTable.Cell(3, 2).Range.Text)))
        ThisYrWinCon = CInt(Left(tTable.Cell(3, 2).Range.Text, Len(tTable.Cell(3, 2).Range.Text) - 1))
        PreYrSumCon = CInt(Left(tTable.Cell(2, 3).Range.Text, Len(tTable.Cell(3, 2).Range.Text)))
        PreYrWinCon = CInt(Left(tTable.Cell(3, 3).Range.Text, Len(tTable.Cell(3, 2).Range.Text)))
        BePreYrSumCon = CInt(Left(tTable.Cell(2, 4).Range.Text, Len(tTable.Cell(3, 2).Range.Text)))
        BePreYrWinCon = CInt(Left(tTable.Cell(3, 4).Range.Text, Len(tTable.Cell(3, 2).Range.Text)))

        'MsgBox (ThisYrSumCon)

        'cTable.Cell(3, 4).Range.Text = "test"
        'cTable.Cell(12, 3).Range.Text = "test"


        Set wChart = ActiveDocument.Shapes.AddChart.Chart
        With wChart.Parent
            .Top = 105
            .Left = 205
            .Width = 300
            .Height = 150
        End With



        Set chartWorkSheet = wChart.ChartData.Workbook.WorkSheets(1)
        chartWorkSheet.ListObjects("Table1").Resize chartWorkSheet.Range("A1:G2")
        chartWorkSheet.Range("Table1[[#Headers],[Series 1]]").FormulaR1C1 = "Water Consumption Records"
        wChart.ChartType = xlColumnClustered


        chartWorkSheet.Range("A1").FormulaR1C1 = ""
        chartWorkSheet.Range("B1").FormulaR1C1 = "2012 Summer"
        chartWorkSheet.Range("C1").FormulaR1C1 = "2012 Winter"
        chartWorkSheet.Range("D1").FormulaR1C1 = "2013 Summer"
        chartWorkSheet.Range("E1").FormulaR1C1 = "2013 Winter"
        chartWorkSheet.Range("F1").FormulaR1C1 = "2014 Summer"
        chartWorkSheet.Range("G1").FormulaR1C1 = "2014 Winter"

        chartWorkSheet.Range("A2").FormulaR1C1 = ""
        chartWorkSheet.Range("B2").FormulaR1C1 = BePreYrSumCon
        chartWorkSheet.Range("C2").FormulaR1C1 = BePreYrWinCon
        chartWorkSheet.Range("D2").FormulaR1C1 = PreYrSumCon
        chartWorkSheet.Range("E2").FormulaR1C1 = PreYrWinCon
        chartWorkSheet.Range("F2").FormulaR1C1 = ThisYrSumCon
        chartWorkSheet.Range("G2").FormulaR1C1 = ThisYrWinCon

        wChart.ChartData.Workbook.Application.Quit


        i = i + 5
        j = j + 5
        Selection.GoTo What:=wdGoToPage, Which:=lNextPage


Next
```

Answer (score 1):

Lol, I am so happy that I can answer my own question... :)

Here's the answer for creating a chart base on the same format word table in each page, and put the chart at same spot each page.

The i Integer is for me to find the same table in each page.

```
Dim Rng As Range, pg As Long
Dim i As Integer
i = 3

With ActiveDocument
    Set Rng = .Range(0, 0)
    For pg = 1 To .ComputeStatistics(wdStatisticPages)
        Set Rng = Rng.GoTo(What:=wdGoToPage, Which:=wdGoToAbsolute, Count:=pg)

        Rng.Collapse wdCollapseStart

        Dim tTable As Table
        Set tTable = ActiveDocument.Tables(i)

        Dim wChart As Chart
        Dim chartWorkSheet As Excel.Worksheet
        Dim ThisYrSumCon As Integer
        Dim ThisYrWinCon As Integer
        Dim PreYrSumCon As Integer
        Dim PreYrWinCon As Integer
        Dim BefPreYrSumCon As Integer
        Dim BefPreYrWinCon As Integer

        ThisYrSumCon = CInt(Left(tTable.Cell(2, 2).Range.Text, Len(tTable.Cell(2, 2).Range.Text) - 1))
        ThisYrWinCon = CInt(Left(tTable.Cell(3, 2).Range.Text, Len(tTable.Cell(3, 2).Range.Text) - 1))
        PreYrSumCon = CInt(Left(tTable.Cell(2, 3).Range.Text, Len(tTable.Cell(2, 3).Range.Text) - 1))
        PreYrWinCon = CInt(Left(tTable.Cell(3, 3).Range.Text, Len(tTable.Cell(3, 3).Range.Text) - 1))
        BePreYrSumCon = CInt(Left(tTable.Cell(2, 4).Range.Text, Len(tTable.Cell(2, 4).Range.Text) - 1))
        BePreYrWinCon = CInt(Left(tTable.Cell(3, 4).Range.Text, Len(tTable.Cell(3, 4).Range.Text) - 1))

        Set wChart = .Shapes.AddChart(xlColumnClustered, 270, 105, 230, 150, Rng).Chart
        Set chartWorkSheet = wChart.ChartData.Workbook.WorkSheets(1)
        chartWorkSheet.ListObjects("Table1").Resize chartWorkSheet.Range("A1:G2")
        chartWorkSheet.Range("Table1[[#Headers],[Series 1]]").FormulaR1C1 = "Water Consumption Records"


        chartWorkSheet.Range("A1").FormulaR1C1 = ""
        chartWorkSheet.Range("B1").FormulaR1C1 = "2012 Summer"
        chartWorkSheet.Range("C1").FormulaR1C1 = "2012 Winter"
        chartWorkSheet.Range("D1").FormulaR1C1 = "2013 Summer"
        chartWorkSheet.Range("E1").FormulaR1C1 = "2013 Winter"
        chartWorkSheet.Range("F1").FormulaR1C1 = "2014 Summer"
        chartWorkSheet.Range("G1").FormulaR1C1 = "2014 Winter"

        chartWorkSheet.Range("A2").FormulaR1C1 = ""
        chartWorkSheet.Range("B2").FormulaR1C1 = BePreYrSumCon
        chartWorkSheet.Range("C2").FormulaR1C1 = BePreYrWinCon
        chartWorkSheet.Range("D2").FormulaR1C1 = PreYrSumCon
        chartWorkSheet.Range("E2").FormulaR1C1 = PreYrWinCon
        chartWorkSheet.Range("F2").FormulaR1C1 = ThisYrSumCon
        chartWorkSheet.Range("G2").FormulaR1C1 = ThisYrWinCon

        wChart.ChartData.Workbook.Application.Quit

        i = i + 5
        j = j + 5

    Next
End With
```